# Jena OSGi bundle cannot start

Tags: osgi, jena

I want to use Jena OSGi 3.0.0 version in Felix 2.0.3, but when I install the bundle I get the exception:

```
Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.jena.osgi [1]: package; (&(package=org.apache.commons.cli)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
```

Does this mean that the package `org.apache.commons.cli` is not contained in the jena-osgi bundle?
Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=org.apache.commons.cli in my configuration but the same problem persists.

Comment: Please ignore the answers given by @PeterPenzov, they are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this means that the jena-osgi bundle imports package `org.apache.commons.cli`. You need to install the bundle that exports this package.

Funnily enough, this package is exported by a bundle named `org.apache.commons.cli` which you can get from Maven Central:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|commons-cli|commons-cli|1.3.1|jar

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This causes another unresolved constraint error: 'Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.jena.osgi [1]: package; (&(package=org.apache.thrift.protocol)(version>=0.9.0)(!(version>=1.0.0)))'.

Comment: Just keep going. Now you need a bundle that exports org.apache.thrift.protocol. Just a guess, but maybe [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) can provide that package...